# CSS nested class definition

Tags: css, sass

My apologies because of maybe stupid question >_<

Does below way of css definition exist officially?
In which cases such coding could be used?
Can you provide some documentation about this way?

```css
.outer-class {
  // style declaration

  .inner-class {
    // style declaration
  }
}
```

Comment: it will be valid in the near future but actually it's not. This a SASS syntax

Comment: This can be done using SCSS.

Comment: Thank you guys, I misunderstood with css!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some kind of preprocessor that compiles to native `css`. Unfortunately, the current `CSS` specification doesn't support nesting in styles.

For instance, you can use `scss` that supports this kind of code & compiles it to native `CSS` like the following:

```css
.outer-class {
  // style declaration
}

.outer-class .inner-class {
  // style declaration
 }
```

You can read more at: [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sass/sass_nesting.asp).